server gets a new ip-address every time I reboot on Ubuntue 20.04
I have a Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS using dhcp.  Everytime I reboot the ip-address gets changed but not DNS.  I'd like to keep the same ip-address.  I have changed my /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml as :
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: true
      critical: true
      #       dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.3.XXX.XXX/24]
      nameservers:
          search: [mydomain.org]
          addresses: [10.3.XXX.XXX,130.221.XXX.XXX]

I have not run the "netplan apply" since I am not confident of my changes.
Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Is your system configured to vary its MAC address for privacy reasons? If yes, the changing IP address will be caused by that.

Thanks for the reply.
No, it is not for varying mac-address.
what I posted is a modified netplan config file.  Do you think the ip-address persists after the reboot?

When you specify dhcp4: true, you cause your system to broadcast, on the local LAN (all the systems reachable by MAC Address of all ONEs) a "Who has the IP Address of MAC Address ". Your router responds (to your MAC Address) with "IP Address x.x.x.x is associated with Your MAC Address". The length of time the IP Address is valid, whether the IP Address is assigned from the pool, or as an out-of-pool/permanent (but still inside the subnet range) address, MTU, and more has to be done on the router (the DHCP Server), not on your DHCP client.

The DHCP specification says the DHCP server should generally at least make an attempt to remember the MAC -> IP associations and keep giving the same IP address to the same client if practical. However some Internet Service Providers may configure their DHCP servers to vary the public IP addresses they hand out on basic consumer-grade internet connections to discourage users from setting up servers unless paying extra for the privilege. But that does not seem likely here as you're using the private 10.0.0.0/8 address block.

Thank you all for the comments but, I am still not clear weather the changes I have made (shown in my original post) keeps the same ip-address after a reboot?  do I need to specify/set the mac-address in my config file.  Is that what is missing?

Another issue I just noticed is that the DNS has one ip-address (previous assigned dhcp ip-address) and NIC enp5s0 has another one.  This behavior keeps happening after a reboot.  DNS does not match the hosts ip-address.

@waltinator you seem to be describing ARP; DHCP is slightly different.
